# Yesod get a one to many relationship from database

Tags: database, haskell, orm, yesod

I have two tables `product` and `category` defined like below:

```
Product
  category CategoryId
  name Text
  description Text
  price Int
Category
  name Text
```

I would like to extract from the database a list of type `[(Category, [Product])]`. How would I go about this in Yesod?

I am completely new and have looked for pretty much a whole day trying to find something to do this.

**Update**

This is my hamlet

```
$if null rows
  <p>No products
$else
  <div class="list-group menu">
    $forall (category, [products]) <- rows
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">#{categoryName category}

      $forall product <- products
       <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p>#{productName product} - #{productPrice product}</p>
          <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></div></a>
              <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two basic approaches would be:

1. Get the list of all categories, and then for each category, get a list of products
2. Use esqueleto to do an inner (or left) join, and then use sort and group function in Haskell

The first approach is probably simpler. Here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class  (liftIO)
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.Sqlite
import           Database.Persist.TH
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Monad (forM)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Product
  category CategoryId
  name Text
  description Text
  price Int
  deriving Show
Category
  name Text
  deriving Show
|]

main :: IO ()
main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
    runMigrationSilent migrateAll
    populate
    res <- query
    liftIO $ print res

populate = do
    watches <- insert $ Category "Watches"
    insert_ $ Product watches "Rolex" "Fancy" 100
    insert_ $ Product watches "Limex" "Cheap" 2

    computers <- insert $ Category "Computers"
    insert_ $ Product computers "MacBook Air" "Apple" 1500

query = do
    cats <- selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]
    forM cats $ \(Entity catId cat) -> do
        products <- selectList
            [ProductCategory ==. catId]
            [Asc ProductName]
        return (cat, map entityVal products)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I think that is working. My only problem is that in my hamlet I am trying to loop through the list and it is saying `Couldn't match type ‘Product’ with ‘t0 Product’`. Do you know what that is or do you need more information to answer this? Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like you're using one for all, when you actually need two (outer and inner list). But I can't be sure without seeing your hamlet

Comment: I've added the hamlet to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Drop the square brackets on product in the first forall. On my phone, can't elaborate